# fit seekBar inside a drawer

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout, android-seekbar

how i can fit a seekBar to stay inside a drawer boundary?

this is my `drawerLayout`

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#123456"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

with this code, the seekBar is shown inside the `drawerLayout`, not inside the rightDrawer boundary.

**UPDATE NOW LOOKS**
[image]

**I WANT THIS**

[image]
is it possible to achieve this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: The seekBar is shown inside the drawerLayout but not inside the rightDrawer boundary.? what do u mean exactly?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan see question update.

Comment: @HarshaVardhan i want the seekBar to stay inside the rightDrawer layout.

Comment: You can put some dummy pic, how it should look and now how it is looking...

Comment: @HarshaVardhan now it's complete, look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not having framelayout. so, ur linearlayout has taken in the place of that.

modify ur layout as follows

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:max="5"
            android:progress="0" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#123456"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: this is not a solution

Comment: Yokupoku Maioku, check the image added. This is what you have asked

Comment: Set the `layout_gravity="right"` and `layout_width="240dp"` attributes on the LinearLayout that holds the SeekBar and ListView.